# WPF MenuItem template for MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

I am having trouble write the xaml representation to allow to bind to my background ViewModel for cascading menus

here's the VM:

```
public class MenuNode
{
  public string Header {get;}
  public List<MenuNode> Items {get;}
}
```

the xaml i have is this:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" >
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmi:MenuNode}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```

When the menu pops up I get the first-level entries with an arrow(indicating that there should be a sub-menu) but when i hover over the menu it doesn't show the sub-menu items.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you are adding the items after the binding is initialized? Maybe you need to use ObservableCollection<MenuNode> instead of List<MenuNode> so the items collection gets notified.

Comment: The trick with MenuItem and TabItem item generation is filling the header / icon areas. You have to use the ItemContainerStyle to do it, and it is tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here's the issue:

For some reason, the `MenuItems` that were generated by your `DataTemplate` are getting wrapped inside of another `MenuItem` (the result was nested `MenuItems`). The sub items were not being opened because the outer `MenuItem` had no children.

The solution is to use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" >
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmi:MenuNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 4):

my take on MenuItems and MVVM (it was not easy to put Icons in there)

```
  public class MenuItemVM
  {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItemVM> Children { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
  }

public IList<MenuItemVM> AddContextMenu { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<Image x:Key="MenuItemIcon"
       x:Shared="false"
       Source="{Binding Icon}"
       Height="16px"
       Width="16px"/>

<Style x:Key="ContextMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}"/>
  <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <!-- insert a null in ItemsSource if you want a separator -->
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
      <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Add the contextmenu to your UI

```
<ContextMenu ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContextMenuItemStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding AddContextMenu}">
  <ContextMenu.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmp:MenuItemVM}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ObservableCollection<MenuNode>` instead of `List<MenuNode>` if you are adding the nodes to the list after the binding is initialized the items collection will not get updated unless you are firing `INotifyCollectionChanged` (`ObservableCollection` does this).

Comment: not the issue, because the object is initialized before binding takes place

Comment: OK, I figured it probably wouldn't be. Let me do some checking on this. At first glance, your code looks great.

Comment: I will switch it to ObservableCollection<> to see if it makes a difference, maybe it should be hierarchicaltemplate?

Comment: Bingo. It should be HierarchicalDataTemplate. Your XAML looks like it should work, but for some reason the MenuItems in the template are getting wrapped in another MenuItem by the item container.